# Inequality with logarithmic identity

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, power-series

Prove that $$\frac{1}{3n^2}<\log \left({{n+1} \over {n-1}} \right)^{\frac{n}{2}}-1<\frac{1}{3(n^2-1)}$$ for all $n>2$.

Comment: $n=1$ is not possible!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thanks for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your equation can be rewritten using $x=1/n$ as
$$
\frac{x^2}3<\frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)}{2x}-1<\frac{x^2}{3(1-x^2)}
$$

Using the logarithmic series for $|x|<1$, i.e., $n>1$, gives
\begin{align}
\frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)}{2x}
&=1+\frac{x^2}3+\frac{x^4}5+…+\frac{x^{2k}}{2k+1}+…
\\
&=1+\frac{x^2}3\left(1+\frac{3x^2}5+…+\frac{3x^{2k}}{2k+3}+…\right)
\end{align}

Using the Bernoulli inequality the coefficients can be bounded by
$$(\frac35)^k=\frac1{(1+\frac23)^k}<\frac3{3+2k}<1.$$ 
This results in the lower bound
$$
\frac{x^2}3\left(1+\frac35x^2+\bigl(\frac35\bigr)^2x^4+…\right)
=\frac{x^2}{3(1-\frac35x^2)}
$$
and the upper bound

$$
\frac{x^2}3(1+x^2+x^4+…)
=\frac{x^2}{3(1-x^2)}.
$$
Combined they give the stated result 
$$
\frac{x^2}{3}<\frac{5x^2}{15-3x^2}
<\frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)}{2x}-1
<\frac{x^2}{3(1-x^2)}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\ln \left(\left({{n+1} \over {n-1}} \right)^{\frac{n}{2}}\right)=\frac{n}{2}\left(\ln (n+1)-\ln(n-1)\right)$

$\ln (n+1) = \ln n -\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k(n)^k}\\
\ln (n-1) = \ln n -\sum_\limits{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1)^k}{k(n)^k}$

$\frac 2n + \frac 2{3n^3}<\ln (n+1) - \ln(n-1)$

$\frac 1{3n^2}<\ln \left(\left({{n+1} \over {n-1}} \right)^{\frac{n}{2}}\right)-1$